# Border of the control is not displayed at appropriate time

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a designer like Visual Studio.

Suppose I have a Grid.
Inside that I have a TextBox and a TextBlock. For better understanding look at the sample code below:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DodgerBlue" />
           </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Border Style="myStyle">
    <Grid>
        <Border Style="myStyle">
            <TextBox ...... />
        </Border>
        <Border Style="myStyle">
            <TextBlock ...... />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Now when I mouseOver on any of the element I want to get a border around it.

My Problems:

1. I get a border around grid as well as a border around textblock when mouse cursor is over textblock.
2. When my mouse cursor goes over empty area of grid the border is not shown.

Requirements :

1. when mouse cursor goes over textblock, the border around grid should become invisible.
2. when mouse cursor goes over empty area in grid, the border around grid should become visible.

Please suggest the changes that I should make in the above code to have the required functionality.

Comment: @Blam I mean when my cursor goes just over the grid's transparent border, I can see the Border of DodgerBlue Colour. But when my cursor moves over the empty area of the grid (except Border area), I cannot see the Border.

Comment: Fix the question.  Clearly define required functionality.

Comment: @Blam I have updated my question as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you assign myStyle to the outter Border? Just leave that out.

Comment: But I want to styled it the same way as the its child controls.

Answer (score 0):

1: I think, your idea with glowing parent border is not good. Because it will be blink whenever user hold mouse over the grid. Perhaps, it will annoy user :)

2: Try to set Grid.Background="Transparent".

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding my question completely. To Better understand my problem open visual studio and create a project of type WPF Application. Place a Border and then place a Grid inside it. Now place a border inside Grid and place a TextBlock inside this border. Don't run the project and just mouse over the Grid, empty area of the grid and the textblock. I want to have that same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Grid Background="LightGray" >
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Grid_Bd" Duration="0:0:0.1"></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Grid_Bd" Duration="0:0:0.1"></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Grid Height="50"  Width="50">
            <Border x:Name="TextBlock_Bd" Opacity="0"  BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello !!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock_Bd" Duration="0:0:0.1"></DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock_Bd" Duration="0:0:0.1"></DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </TextBlock.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Border x:Name="Grid_Bd" Opacity="0"  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>                           
    </Grid>
```